# edit html pages using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to edit html pages using java. is it possible. ( it is required for my project, if I automate the test cases using selenium when it passes then the result comes in the company provided HTML sheet)

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Download a page, then edit and send to someone)? Just create your own HTML with test results?

Comment: I want to create my own HTML page using java

Comment: Just use something like this: http://www.ontestautomation.com/create-your-own-html-report-from-selenium-tests/

Comment: exactly like this, Thank you.But I didn't understand well. Is there any alternate solution other than this

Comment: Alternatives? Yes, sure. Just check the answers for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650506/how-to-generate-html-code-programatically-in-java and for example this lib http://j2html.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `JavaFX` as GUI you can use its built in [HTML editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/editor.htm#CHDBEGDD).

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a lot of differnt ways to edit html.

If you want to parse HTML code and manipulate it, http://jsoup.org/ is a very good solution.